# Varaible in If statement in ActionListener

Tags: java, variables, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

I'm making an app, with multiple classes, and in one class i have some code to assign a random number from 1 - 6 to a variable. In another class i have a JLabel showing this variable. And in another class i have a JButton, with a ActionListener, within this is an IF Statement, with the variable with the random number in.

The variable is in Class1.

```
package Dice;

public class DiceRoll {

public int DICEONE;
public int DICETWO;

private int max = 6;
private int min = 1;

public void DiceRollMethod() {

    DICEONE = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);
    DICETWO = (int) (Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min);

    System.out.println(DICEONE);
    System.out.println(DICETWO);

}
}
```

The variable is 'DICEONE'

The JLabel is in Class2 (which rolls the dice).

```
package Dice;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DiceButton extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    DiceRoll roll = new DiceRoll();

    JButton btnRoll;
    public JLabel DB1, DB2;

    public DiceButton() {
        DB1 = new JLabel("Dice 1: " + roll.DICEONE);
        DB2 = new JLabel("Dice 2: " + roll.DICETWO);
        DB1.setVisible(true);
        DB2.setVisible(true);

        btnRoll = new JButton("Roll Dice");
        btnRoll.setVisible(true);
        btnRoll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                roll.DiceRollMethod();
                DB1.setText("Dice 1: " + roll.DICEONE);
                DB2.setText("Dice 2: " + roll.DICETWO);

            }

        });
        add(DB1);
        add(DB2);
        add(btnRoll);


    }

}
```

When the button is clicked, the random number is assigned to the variable and then displayed.

Finally the variable is used in the ActionListener in Class3 (this is the bit i have a problem with).

```
package Tiles;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

import Dice.DiceButton;
import Dice.DiceRoll;

public class SpaceOne extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    DiceRoll roll = new DiceRoll();
    DiceButton dButton = new DiceButton();

    JButton btn1;
    JLabel lbl1;



    Font lblFont = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 90);
    Border lblBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3);

    public SpaceOne() {

        setSize(50,100);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

        lbl1 = new JLabel("1");
        lbl1.setVisible(true);
        lbl1.setFont(lblFont);
        lbl1.setBorder(lblBorder);
        lbl1.setLocation(1, 1);


        btn1 = new JButton("1");
        btn1.setVisible(true);
        btn1.setLocation(1, 2);
        btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                if(roll.DICEONE == 1) {
                    lbl1.setText(".");
                    System.out.println("DICEONE");
                }else if(roll.DICETWO == 1) {
                    lbl1.setText(".");
                    System.out.println("DICETWO");
                }

            }

        });
        add(btn1);
        add(lbl1);
    }

}
```

The idea is that when the button is clicked, it will check if the variable is equal to a number, and if it is, to change the JLabel text.

But when I click the button nothing changes. The button to roll the dice works fine.

Comment: Something will only happen if one of the rolls is equal to 1. Have you debugged to check what they actually are?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: consider adding `else` block for debugging purpose